# Java - Simplest Radical Form

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, math, solver

I was trying to build a program that puts a radical into simplest radical form. I, ovbiously, had no luck.

I am looking for a method that takes in a `String` and returns a `String`.

An input `String`: `sqrt[160]`. I have already made my method take the numerical value out (160).

Now, I just need something to break 160 up and return a `String` like: `"4*sqrt[10]"`

Thanks in advance!

NOTE:

1. The above is JUST AN EXAMPLE

Comment: It will help if you (1) make your example consistent and correct, and (2) show us the code you've got so far.

Comment: Err, `4*sqrt[10]` is √160, not √120

Comment: Are you looking for a symbolic math library? You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3587557/341970) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorize the number, all factors with the exponent of power of two can be moved outside the square root. Multiply the rest, that will remain under the root symbol.

Comment: A straightforward way: start divide the number starting from 2. If the current number is a divider, store it as a factor and increment its exponent by one. If not, go for the next number (not actually making the division). Repeat until the result of the division is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Define "simplest radical form".

Since when is `sqrt(120) = 4*sqrt(10)`?  My calculator tells me that `10.954 != 12.649`.  Is this a typo?  Maybe you meant `sqrt(160)`.

What makes your form simpler?

The method interface is easy; the logic to implement is harder.  You'll have to break the value under the square root sign into integer factors and look for perfect square roots.